# Add a link to another method in the @see section of headerdoc

Tags: objective-c, xcode, documentation, headerdoc

I'm trying to add a link to a UIKit method in my own documentation.
According to [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/anchors/anchors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001215-CH347-SW15), I should add a `@see` tag with an `//apple_ref/` link.

Here's my documentation :

```
/**
 * Creates and add constraints to the receiver
 *
 * @return The constraints that were added.
 *
 * @see //apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:
 */
```

And here's the result:
[image: screenshot]

Any idea how should I do it ?

**EDIT**: Same question goes for `@see` in the same file.